# Swift 5 URLSession API Class Throwing Weird Errors

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, urlsession

learning Swift with SwiftUI right now. I'm trying to build a class that handles an API but having a LOT of difficulty.

So I have a stock prices function that I want to call from this API anytime someone loads a view and then I want this function to return the proper list of stock price objects so that I can render it into a chart.

For some reason I'm having an issue with Result not having a .success function.

Would love to know thoughts here!

This is my code right now:

```
final class StockAPI{


func fetchData(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (Result) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let json: [String: Any] = ["symbol": symbol]
    
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    request.httpBody = jsonData


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            //completion(.error(error.localizedDescription as! Error), error)
            return
      }

        do{
            let stockPrices = try? JSONDecoder().decode([StockPrice].self, from: data!)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // update our UI
                print("Dispatching request")
                completion(.success(from: stockPrices as! Decoder))
            }
            
        } catch let jsonError {
            return
        }
      
    })
    
    task.resume()
  }
```

Comment: ok so i replaced the error with completion but I'm getting a Result' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context on the func definition line.

Comment: OK this is really starting to frustrate me. So I did do that and swift refuses to build this:

func getTheList(completion: @escaping (Result<[StockPrice], Error>) -> Void) 


above results in 

'Result' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Result'
Remove '<[StockPrice], Error>'

Comment: then when i remove it, it tells me to add back in the arguments. not sure what's happening

Comment: holy hell you've just saved me! This works and thanks for the example!

This was an interesting learning experience. Do you have any good books/references I can use for Swift?

Comment: My pleasure. And, no, I haven't kept up with the literature so I'm not sure I'm in a place to recommend titles for you. I'm personally a visual learner, so I try to find video resources, of which Stanford and LinkedIn Learning are my go to recommendations, if out of date. (And, unfortunately, it's considered off topic for S.O., so if you try to post a question asking for those resources, you'll be shouted down.)

Comment: gotcha yeah that makes sense. thanks for the help and references though!

Answer (score 0):

In your two error conditions (network error and parsing error) you should call your completion closure with `.failure` and the error. Right now you’re flying blind.

The use of `Result` is curious, as it is a generic and is usually of the form of `Result<[StockPrice], Error`> (i.e., specifying what the success type is, i.e., `[StockPrice]`, and what the failure type is, i.e., `Error`). Result is a generic and you want to specify what types the associated types for `.success` and `.failure` are.

So, it would probably be something like:

```swift
func fetchData(symbol: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[StockPrice], Error>) -> Void) { // if you have compilation error here, try `Swift.Result<[StockPrice], Error>` instead
    let url = URL(string: "https://google.com")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let object = ["symbol": symbol]

    request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(object) // or wrap this in `do`-`catch` block and use `try` without the `!`
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }

        do {
            let stockPrices = try JSONDecoder().decode([StockPrice].self, from: data!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // update our UI
                print("Dispatching request")
                completion(.success(stockPrices))
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            completion(.failure(jsonError))
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```